# How to prevent link_to icon change color on hover?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm creating simple app using RoR.

I have a link which looks like this

```
 <%= link_to (fa_icon "heart-o", class: "fa-lg"), like_path %>
```

When the mouse is over the icon I cannot longer see the icon, I see just black square in a size of the icon.
I was able to set the visited color and it works fine but I'm not able to change the hover option.

Any ideas?

@edit: I was sure it worked before, so I've created a branch from one of my old commits in repository and applied changes to the code step by step checking when it stopped working. The app didn't load my scss files, except application.scss so I added:

```
/*
*= require_tree
*/
```

to my application.scss and then it stopped working.

@edit2: I've solved the problem, there was hover background color deffined in scaffolds.scss. I removed that and everything works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: It's a CSS thing. You just have to write a CSS rule for `a.fa-lg::hover`, or add a second class and make the rule for that class.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc it's not that simple, I've already tried that

Comment: Happy you got it solved. It's almost always just a simple CSS thing with visual stuff, very (very) rarely it will be some JavaScript thing, but it's almost always just a CSS rule.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple like this in css:

```
a.fa-lg:hover {
    color: #3af !important;
}
```

Comment: @Meii try with !important. It must be that simple believe me.

Comment: Still doesn't work for the hover, I mean not matter what I add I can see the heart in it's color but all the empty space in the square is filled with black